# Raspberry Pi Pico load values from config file

Tags: c, embedded, config, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using the C, C++ SDK for RPI Pico. I have written a C program that gets a value from a config text file then uses the said value for various purposes.

The problem is that I want to give this to an end user. And I thought that the easiest thing would be to give them the uf2 file and this config text file, and they could put the RPI Pico in Mass storage mode and play with the config as they see fit.

But if I move the config and *.uf2 file to the Pico it will not actually read any data from this config file.

Is there a way to do this? Or should I look into a different approach? I would need the simplest approach possible, because I am very much a newbie in embedded programming, also I would rather not add hardware components, like extra memory or dipswitches (to set the values). I also need this value to be stored after a power outage (so it's not okay if the end-user sets the values through some serial means, or any other means that would not persist a power-cycle and are volatile.).